# What is the difference between sizeLimit under volumes vs ephemeral-storage under limits

Tags: kubernetes

1. pod.spec.containers.resources.limits.ephemeral-storage
2. pod.spec.volumes.emptyDir.sizeLimit

**Scenario**
Say I have 2 containers. Both the containers utilize the same 2 volumes.

volume 1 -> sizeLimit = 10Ki

volume 2 -> sizeLimit = 20Ki

container 1 (limits.ephemeral-storage) -> 4Ki

container 2 (limits.ephemeral-storage) -> 4Ki

When will the pod get evicted with these configs?

Answer (score 1):

Pods use ephemeral local storage for scratch space, caching, and logs. The kubelet can provide scratch space to Pods using local ephemeral storage to mount **emptyDir** volumes into containers.

If a Pod is using more ephemeral storage than you allow it to, the kubelet sets an eviction signal that triggers Pod eviction.

For container-level isolation, if a container's writable layer and log usage exceed its storage limit, the kubelet marks the Pod for eviction.

In your case when it is exceeding the limit associated with the container it will be set for eviction.

More details here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/